# Not able to parse when String has dot

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to convert `String temp = 129.70` to number.

**I tried:**

```
String decimalNumber= "-129.70";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(decimalNumber));
```

But it is giving me exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-129.70"`

Answer (score 1):

129.70 is not an integer. It's a double. Change class and you should be fine.

```
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(decimalNumber))
```

Comment: Tried and it worked, I am surprised it was not available on any threads on google.

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
    String decimalNumber= "-129.70";
    System.out.println(Integer.parseDouble(decimalNumber));
```

Comment: All you would get by trying this is a compiler error, because `Integer.parseDouble` does not exist (unless this is some `Integer` class other than `java.lang.Integer`).